# Ordnance Survey Grids

Tags: ordnance-survey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ordnance Survey grids - download or generate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate)

Does anyone know if I can download a grid of the tile locations for the 1:10k, 1:25k and 1:50k Ordnance Survey tile locations?

I know you can download the tfw/tab files for each tile, but I do not have the images. Is it possible to create this grid using tfw/tab files without the image files?

Comment: Just found http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate. Will use this.

Comment: James, I'm glad you've found your answer -- I'm closing this question as it appears to be a duplicate.