# Ordnance Survey 1 km Grid

Tags: shapefile, vector, coordinates, ordnance-survey, download

I am wanting to get a copy of the OS 1km Grid layer.

I have found these previous questions:

- [Ordnance Survey grids - download or generate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate)
  and
- [Ordnance Survey Grids](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/ordnance-survey-grids)

But neither provide the information I required.

The first question does provide some links to the OS web site but these now return the 404 error. A subsequent comment mentions its half way down this page:

- https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

But which specific item should I be downloading? It is not obvious!

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data you download? If you provide us with a bit of background on your project we can advise you on the best dataset to download.

Comment: Currently I'm wanting to use this layer to allow me to produce a list of the selected 1km grid squares. The list then used to select the corresponding tiles of LiDAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link where you can download the whole set in ESRI Shapefile format

[Download Here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/oscustomers/OSGrids_Shape.zip)

This will probably be up for a few days so can you please download ASAP

Comment: While the answer is correct, if the link is only up for a few days then this thread will suffer the same fate as the previous two.

Comment: @Vesanto totally understand but will need to check internally how Ordnance Survey can best do this for other users rather than keep it where it is.

Comment: Not sure if the license for this dataset would allow it, but I could upload this to GitHub which would be as stable a home as we can get right now.

Comment: With regard to the license, the best option would be to stick an Open Data license on it if we can. E.g., http://opendatacommons.org/

Comment: I've added the files to Github and created GeoJSON versions so that can be previewed/used from there directly. Take a look: https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids. Note, the 1km GeoJSON layer is too big to preview in GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

Many of these answers are now out of date with dead links.

There is useful github here with OS National Grid Shapefiles at various scales:

https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids

Answer (score 2):

These can be found [here](http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/sharegeo/handle/10389/131). These were found via the wonderful ShareGeo website: http://edina.ac.uk/projects/sharegeo/content.html

Edit - they can be quite slow to load - but do cover the entirety of Great Britain. No coverage for Northern Ireland unfortunately:

[image: 1km grid]

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to Edina, my student access ran out a few years ago!

Comment: I'm confident you can still apply for access, even if no longer registered at a formal academic establishment. My understanding was that ShareGeo is for the University of Life - will be disappointed if you can't gain access. Try here: https://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/password-login

Comment: OS doesn't map NI so that is why there is no coverage.

Comment: I'm surprised the 1km grid is not downloadable directly from the OS website.

Comment: Me too. Any luck getting an Edina login? May take some time to process your request. Best of luck with it.

Comment: I would need to have the Terms and Conditions approved by my employer before creating an account. Which is a massive shame.

Answer (score 0):

About as accurate as I have seen:

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/maps/national-grid-map.pdf (from the OpenData page)

The previous post is referencing PAI (OS Positional Accuracy Improvement), which was done about a decade ago now, so obsolete and hence the 404.

I don't think there is a 1km grid layer.

Answer (score 0):

Ordnance Survey's GitHub organisation now has a repository containing a GeoPackage of these grids at various resolutions (including 1 km): https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-British-National-Grids.