# Seeking elevation data for UK?

Tags: dem, united-kingdom, data

I'm looking for digital elevation data for UK.

Does anybody know if there is a good service providing data for free that are of better accuracy than ASTER-DEM that is around 30m and, if not, what is the best service for paid data with accuracy around 10m?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordnance Survey grids - download or generate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on Open Data SE

Answer (score 8):

The Ordnance Survey have Landform Profile and [Landform Panorama](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) that were based on their contour data, but it is not fantastic quality, and it is based on very old data. But it is now free to download, so if you just need a dataset to play with, it's a good choice.

I've used GetMapping's [NEXTMap Britain 2](http://www1.getmapping.com/Products/NEXTMap-Britain-2) lidar data, and it is of generally very good quality, providing both a "treetops" dataset, and a "bare earth" dataset. But the tiles are very expensive once you start getting reasonably-sized areas. It has a horizontal resolution of 5m (I think there is a cheaper 10m resolution dataset), and a good vertical resolution (about 20cm IIRC).

### Edit

The Environment Agency has released its LiDAR data on an open source license. It covers about 72% of England and Wales: https://environmentagency.blog.gov.uk/2015/06/16/free-mapping-data-will-elevate-flood-risk-knowledge/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had a look at both I'm just downloading the ordnance survey dataset.

Comment: Please Note: Panorama data was collected between 1970 and 1980. This product has not been updated since this date

Comment: For a New Better Ordnance Survey Product [Terrain 50] See New Question [30th Oct 2013] http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75980/what-is-the-highest-obtainable-resolution-of-free-elevation-data-in-the-uk

Comment: for the EA Lidar, a [coverage map is available here](https://houseprices.io/lab/lidar/map). Doesn't include Wales (to be released soon, I believe), Scotland or NI.

Answer (score 0):

This elevation finder is very good. Just zoom in to a required location, then click on it, and it'll show you the elevation above sea level in metres.

https://www.freemaptools.com/elevation-finder.htm