# What is the highest obtainable resolution of FREE elevation data in the UK?

Tags: dem, elevation, united-kingdom, data

I am seeking closure with this question guys.

I am aware of various sources of free elevation data ~30+ m, and I have been searching for higher resolution FREE data for a while now. This already exists somewhat ([Where to acquire elevation data for UK?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27128/where-to-acquire-elevation-data-for-uk)), but may have changed since a year.

I'm afraid I may know the answer already, but to put an end to my misery and false hope:

**What is the highest resolution, freely available (outside of academic institutions), elevation data covering the ENTIRE UK? - is 10 m available?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**OS Terrain 50 contours** (10m contours) for **Great Britain** (England, Scotland and Wales)

> It is supplied both as a set of 50m gridded digital terrain model (OS
>   Terrain 50 grid) and 10m contours and spot heights (OS Terrain 50
>   contours).

**Notice: OS Terrain 50 contours and OS Terrain 50 grid are now available as of 8th July 2013**.

Tip: Opt for the OS Terrain 50 - ESRI SHAPE (CONTOURS) - GB

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html

Update: 27th October 2015.
With a lot of processing it is possible to get even more detailed elevation data (for England currently) from Environmental Agency Opendata LiDAR example http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey#/download?grid=TL45 has 1m res LiDAR which heights of features (including the ground) can be extracted.

A Example of the contours created from LiDAR are here http://relief.raggedred.net/#18/53.76828/-0.36981 (Layers button 'contours') and zoom in.

Comment: ASTER Gdem is higher resolution (30m) although not as good as panorama.

Comment: Talking to an OS rep the Terrain 50 is better than Panorama as it is topology controlled (i.e all the lines at each elevation are joined unlike panorama) so you can make polygons from the linework.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, is it possible to construct a 10 m resolution DEM from these 10 m contours?

Comment: with the OS Terrain Grid you can (ArcGIS TIN creation then to DEM).