# Highest resolution Digital Elevation Model for the UK?

Tags: data, dem, viewshed, aster

I need the most precise and highest resolution free digital elevation model for the UK.
Would OS terrain 50 or ASTER GDEM be more suitable for view shed analysis?

Comment: Possibly helpful for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118063/highest-resolution-digital-elevation-data

Comment: @Erica - your link points to this question. Where did you meant to point to? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27128/where-to-acquire-elevation-data-for-uk?rq=1 ?

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan Yes, thanks for finding it again -- not sure how I managed that. I'd better go get another cup of coffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ordnance Survey**

As the name suggests, OS Terrain 50 is a product with a 50 metre grid resolution (http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html).

> OS Terrain 50 has been compared with GPS points in a range of sample
>   areas to provide a Route Mean Square Error (RMSE) value for the height
>   points in each geographic area; urban and major communication routes,
>   rural and mountain and moorland. OS Terrain 50 grid has been verified
>   to be 4 m RMSE.

**Satellite DTM's**

ASTER GDEM is about 30metres (http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp).

There's also SRTM, which while it's currently only available at 90 metre accuracy for the UK, will be increasing to 30m (what it is for the USA) within a year (http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2014-321).

For a comparison of the accuracy of these satellite derived products (plus NEXTMap), see this paper:
http://www.asprs.org/a/publications/proceedings/sanantonio09/Tighe_2.pdf
The accuracy varies considerably depending on the surface, the averages being:
`SRTM (15.27 m RMSE), and ASTER (18.52 m RMSE)` while the published RMSE's are 16m and 20m respectively.
Considerably lower than OS Terrain 50.

**Resolution vs Accuracy**

Because OS Terrain 50 is I believe a scaled-down version of flown data, probably in combination with ground survey data, the accuracy is much better than the space-acquired data. On the other hand you have a reduced resolution.

I leave it as an exercise for someone else to determine whether the increased accuracy of OS Terrain 50 offsets the lower resolution.

In short - I don't believe there's a definitive answer, it depends which you value more. I'd guess accuracy is more important for a viewshed though.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose ASTER GDEMv2 as your DEM option, you may transform the Geographic Coordinate System (GCS) from WGS-84 (GCS of Earth) to OSGB-36 (GCS of UK). In this case, you might have more accurate DEM data.

See the comparison between ASTER GDEMv2.0, EU-DEMv1.1, and Google Earth: https://github.com/HeZhang1994/digital-elevation-model-tool-tutorial