# British National Grids projection does not add Ordnance Survey grids to shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, united-kingdom

I have created a shapefile in ArcCatalog by right-clicking the folder I want it in, then selecting new, then shapefile, then changing the type to "polygon", and using the British National Grids under the projected co-ordinate system.

I then tried to add the shapefile in ArcMap by clicking the Add Data button and selecting the shapefile I created.

My problem is that when I open the shapefile in ArcMap, the map is still blank and I cannot see the projected shape of the British National Grids.

Comment: You need to generate your own grid after setting the projection. You can download one from the GISSE answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate

Comment: @Mapperz - The answers on there are a prime example of where answers stagnate over time. I.e. The link in the top-rated answer is now a 404.

Comment: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html - go there and download Strategi for a 50km grid. I don't think any of the other products include a grid.

Answer (score 8):

Specifying "British National Grids" in the projection sets the projection of your data (regardless of what data your shapefile will contain). It **DOES NOT** populate the shapefile with vectors/polygons of the national grids.

In order to see the British National grids as polygons, you need to either find a source that already has the data, or digitize the grids yourself. The answers to [Ordnance Survey grids - download or generate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate) include possible sources for the data.